# Ruby file on execution from command line in Ubuntu generates a blank file

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, ubuntu, haml

I am trying to run a .rb file through the command line in Ubuntu. Although , the execution is not giving any errors, the file generated after the process is a blank one. I have checked all the necessary modules needed like ruby, rails etc and few documentations on the net as well.

Please help me on this.

My code Snippet is given below:

```
<% page_title = "Test Demo Ruby File " %>
<% salutation = "Hello," %>
<html>
<head>
<title><%= page_title %></title>
</head>
<body>
<p><%= salutation %></p>
<p>Successfully template has been loaded in erb</p>
</body>
</html>
```

and I am expecting something like this:

```
<html>
<head>
<title>Test Demo Ruby File </title>
</head>
<body>
<p>Hello,</p>
<p>Successfully template has been loaded in erb</p>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: path>erb  myfilename.rb

Comment: Sir, i am fairly new to ROR  and I dont know much of it. I just read a few articles where they suggested that save the file into a location, then go to the file dir through the command line and run the command as follows

 path>erb myfilename.rb

Answer (score 0):

File generated? The `erb myfilename.rb` command displays the HTML as expected. If you want it in a file, redirect the output:

```
erb myfilename.rb > foo.html
```

`foo.html` will contain the generated HTML. Why are you doing this, if you are using Ruby on Rails?

Comment: Thanks  Satya. That solves the issue. Well, I have to corvert some pre-exisiting  php code to ruby and then the generated html back into haml. For that I have to do this